# Screensavers not showing up in xscreensaver list

Tags: 14.10, screensaver, xscreensaver

I recently switched to xscreensaver in 14.10 and it's running just fine. Except when I added the gluqlo screensaver, it just refuses to show up in the xscreensaver panel.
Might I have missed a step somewhere?

Comment: Anybody? Looking to try anything here.